Azure Document Intelligence Custom Classification Python API
I am making 2 API calls using Python.
url_1 = "https://XXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com/documentintelligence/documentModels/prebuilt-read:analyze?api-version=2024-07-31-preview"
url_2 = "https://XXX.cognitiveservices.azure.com/documentintelligence/documentModels/myModelID:analyze?api-version=2024-07-31-preview"
url = url_1

payload = {}
files=[
  ('',('DOC130924-162130.pdf',open('DOC130924-162130.pdf','rb'),'application/pdf'))
]
headers = { 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXX' }

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.headers)
print(response)
print(response.text)

url_1 works fine and I get 202 response. But for url_2 i get 'The requested model was not found'.
I have only 1 custom classification model and the status is successful from model training. I tested from Azure Document Intelligence Studio and it seems to work fine but not from Python code. Please help.


add screenshot of you custom model you deployed.

@JayashankarGS added screenshot. thanks

Have you deployed the model?

if the status says 'succeeded' it is deployed and that is how it works with custom_extraction and i guess it should be same with custom_classification as well.

ok. still getting same error?

@JayashankarGS finally, found out that the API endpoint was incorrect. it should be documentClassifiers and NOT documentModels

Please add it has an answer so that it will help the community.

Finally fixed it. The URL should include "documentClassifiers" and NOT "documentModels". For custom document classification, use "documentClassifiers". For custom document extraction, use "documentModels". Since Azure Portal does not provide the Python SDK code (at the moment), you will need to dig into the below documentation to find the correct URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aiservices/document-classifiers/classify-document?view=rest-aiservices-v4.0%20(2024-07-31-preview)&viewFallbackFrom=rest-aiservices-2023-07-31&tabs=HTTP
